# Runtime Error on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

Server Error in '/educational/timecalculator' Application.

Runtime Error

**Description**: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

**Details**: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Notes**: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

This website was working before but was moved over to IIS and now getting this error. The webpage will run locally but not remotely. Perhaps the .NET framework isn't 4.5 on IIS?

This is my Web.config file in asp.net

```
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->

<configuration>

<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: The default error page doesn't provide any useful details, which is a sensible security feature. Look in the application event log on the server to find the details of the error. Alternatively, try loading the site from a browser running on the server to see the detailed error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS verify that the Application Pool for the website is set to use the correct .NET Framework.